# Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d=".. for pie chart

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, d3.js

I am creating a donut chart in **d3.js** and AngularJS.
I have a **`drawGraph`** function in directive link function. The data is an array of objects and is coming from server.
Here is what the function looks like.

**Function:**

```
scope.drawGraph = function(data){
            console.log(data);
            var width = 560,
                height = 400,
                radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2.6,
                legendRectSize = 18,
                legendSpacing = 4; 

            var color = d3.scale.category20();

            var pie = d3.layout.pie()
                        .value(function(d) { return d.amount; })
                        .sort(null);

            var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                        .innerRadius(radius - 90)
                        .outerRadius(radius - 70);

            var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
                        .attr("width", width)
                        .attr("height", height)
                        .append("g")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

            var path = svg.selectAll("path")
                        .data(pie(data))
                        .enter().append("path")
                        .attr("fill", function(d, i) {return color(i); })
                        .attr("d", arc);

            var ticks = svg.selectAll("line").data(pie(data)).enter().append("line");
                        ticks.attr("x1", 0)
                        .attr("x2", 0)
                        .attr("y1", -radius+10)
                        .attr("y2", -radius+70)
                        .attr("stroke", "gray")
                        .attr("transform", function(d) {
                          return "rotate(" + (d.startAngle+d.endAngle)/2 * (180/Math.PI) + ")";
                        });

            var labels = svg.selectAll("text").data(pie(data)).enter().append("text");
                        labels.attr("class", "value")
                       .attr("transform", function(d) {
                           var dist=radius+5;
                           var winkel=(d.startAngle+d.endAngle)/2;
                           var x=dist*Math.sin(winkel);
                           var y=-dist*Math.cos(winkel);
                           return "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")";
                        })
                        .attr("dy", "0.35em")
                        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                        .style('fill', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.498039)')
                        .text(function(d){
                            return d.data.category;
                        });
        };

scope.drawGraph(scope.data); // Function call
```

**`scope.data`**:

```
[{amount: 100, category: 'food'},{amount: 150, category: 'fuel'}, {amount: 50, category: 'grocery'},{amount: 250, category: 'Entertainment'}]
```

Here is what the console returns:

> Error: Invalid value for  attribute d="M5.134096196425442e-15,-83.84615384615384A83.84615384615384,83.84615384615384 0 1,1 NaN,NaNLNaN,NaNA63.84615384615384,63.84615384615384 0 1,0 3.909449397278089e-15,-63.84615384615384Z"

And also:

> Error: Invalid value for  attribute d="MNaN,NaNA83.84615384615384,83.84615384615384 0 1,1 NaN,NaNLNaN,NaNA63.84615384615384,63.84615384615384 0 1,0 NaN,NaNZ"
>
> Error: Invalid value for  attribute transform="rotate(NaN)"
>
> Error: Invalid value for  attribute transform="translate(NaN,NaN)"

I am relatively new to d3.js.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please paste your scope.data json data so we can help you

Comment: it's an array of obejcts. I have added it in the code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your code to create a fiddle, and didn't run into the issue you got.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ramseyfeng/zey330m2/)

```
<div id="chart" style="height:500px;">
    <svg></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: @Mak The JSFiddle works for me without any errors. Do you run into errors when executing the fiddle or within your own code? Maybe, you could make a JSFiddle which help reproducing the error for the rest of us.

Comment: I was getting errors in my code. I found out the problem. It was with the scope.data coming from server. Thanks for help.